# YII, вывод из базы, кодировка

Tags: php, mysql, yii

Фреймворк YII, записывает кириллицу в базу нормально, вьюхи отображает нормально, но вывод из базы кириллицы производится некорректно. 
Куда копать?

Comment: вывод куда именно консоль, импорт куда?

Comment: Вывод через find по id, например. Потом через echo в браузер.

Comment: задай header просто так перед выводом `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`

Comment: А кодировка то какая?

Comment: c header все норм работает. Что куда прописать, чтоб не писать каждый раз header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');?

Comment: можно `addCharset` в .htaccess записать http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_mime.html#addcharset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При создании коннекта к mожно, если не ошибаюсь, задать энкодинг при отдаче данных. 
http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.set-charset.php

Но это так же можно по-дефолту сделать, через конфиги самого mysql-а

Что касается УИ: 
у меня есть вот такие настройки в файле config/db.php:

```
return [
    'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
    'dsn' => 'pgsql:host=localhost;dbname=xxxxx',
    'username' => 'xxxxx',
    'password' => 'xxxxxxxxx',
    'charset' => 'utf8',
];
```